# Javascript uppercase words before comma

Tags: javascript

Say I have a list full of names that are formatted like this

> **Stark, Arya C.**

and I want to make all the last names to be changed to

> **STARK, Arya C.**

How do I find the comma in the string and make all the characters before the comma become uppercase characters? I think it requires regex but I don't know how to properly use it since I am still a beginner.

Comment: The simplest option would be to split on comma, uppercase the first part and join again. No regexes needed.

Comment: You need to show some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you tell me more about the list, what is it a text file or array what is it exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add yet another possibility, using the most primitive JavaScript:

```js
var str = "Stark, Arya C.";

var i = str.indexOf(",")+1;
str = str.slice(0, i).toUpperCase() + str.slice(i);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback function. Where you can use [positive lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for getting words which are followed by a comma.

```js
let str = 'Stark, Arya C.';

// use regex to match a word followed by a comma
// where use positive look-ahead assertion for getting the word followed by comma
let res = str.replace(/\w+(?=,)/, m => m.toUpperCase())

console.log(res);
```

---

Or simply with including the comma since  [`String#toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) doesn't make any change to the comma.

```js
let str = 'Stark, Arya C.';

let res = str.replace(/\w+,/, m => m.toUpperCase())

console.log(res);
```

**UPDATE :** If you want to match everything before the comma(including white space) then use `.` instead of `\w`(just for word character). To include newline character use `[\s\S]`.

```js
let str = 'Stark, Arya C.';

let res = str.replace(/.+,/, m => m.toUpperCase())

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`name = name.split(',')[0].toUpperCase() + ',' + name.split(',')[1]`

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a simple way to do it, given there's only one comma.

Comment: It was a typo, I figured I'd be downvoted for something other than a simple typo. Sorry!

Comment: Askers expect answers that work; quality is important. Anyway, I removed my downvote as soon as you fixed your code.

Comment: That's fair. I'll be more careful next time. Thanks!

Comment: You could even get more answers if you explained your code. That way people can learn from it instead of just copying & pasting something from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Split on `,` and join them again after manipulation

```js
let str = 'Stark, Arya C.'

let op = str.split(',')

let final = op[0].toUpperCase() + ',' + op[1]

console.log(final)
```

In case you have more than one comma

```js
let str = 'Stark, Arya C, some more text.'

let splitted = str.split(',')
let last =  splitted.pop()
let withComma = splitted.join(',').toUpperCase()

let final = withComma + ',' + last

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because it does not work when a string has more than one comma.

Comment: @trincot yes it won't but since this is specified in question `list full of names` i didn't considered any case of more than one comma

Answer (score 0):

You can find a first index of `,` in the string using `.indexOf(',')` and pass it to [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that concatenates uppercased (`.toUpprCase()`) substring before that index and the rest of the string.

```js
let name = 'Stark, Arya C.';

name = (idx => name.substr(0, idx).toUpperCase() + name.substr(idx))(name.indexOf(','));

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

```js
var string = "Sheikh, Shoyeb Billings, Sam Demon, Matt";
regex = /(?<= |)\S[A-z]*(?=,)/g;
var modified = string.replace(regex, function (match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(modified);
```